# ambari-agent can not reach ambari-server

Tags: ambari

When I finished install ambari-server with httpd local repository and Comfire Hosts on webUI, I got some error as follow:

```
INFO 2018-05-27 15:39:16,776 NetUtil.py:70 - Connecting to https://master:8440/ca
ERROR 2018-05-27 15:39:16,787 NetUtil.py:96 - [Errno 8] _ssl.c:493: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
ERROR 2018-05-27 15:39:16,788 NetUtil.py:97 - SSLError: Failed to connect.Please check openssl library versions.
Refer to: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1022468 for more details.
WARNING 2018-05-27 15:39:16,789 NetUtil.py:124 - Server at https://master:8440 is not reachable, sleeping for 10 seconds...
INFO 2018-05-27 15:39:26,793 NetUtil.py:70 - Connecting to https://master:8440/ca
ERROR 2018-05-27 15:39:26,799 NetUtil.py:96 - [Errno 8] _ssl.c:493: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
ERROR 2018-05-27 15:39:26,799 NetUtil.py:97 - SSLError: Failed to connect. Please check openssl library versions.Refer to: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1022468 for more details.
WARNING 2018-05-27 15:39:26,801 NetUtil.py:124 - Server at https://master:8440 is not reachable, sleeping for 10 seconds...
```

My environment message as follow:

- CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
- Python2.7.5
- Java1.8.0_171
- OpenSSL1.0.2k
- Ambari2.6.2.0
- HDP-2.6.5.0

On my other amabri-agent nodes, I can reach master on 8440 port as follow:

```
[root@slave2 ~]# telnet master 8440
Trying 192.168.17.128...
Connected to master.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Please give me some help, thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I am having the same issue and the answer below did not help.

Answer (score 1):

I am also getting the same issue.

This worked for me.

In `/etc/ambari-agent/conf/ambari-agent.ini`

Add this line below `[security]`

`force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2`

In `/etc/python/cert-verification.cfg`

```
[https]

verify=disable
```

(change from default to disable)

Answer (score 0):

Please check JAVA_HOME and openSSL version in your setup